# What would cause the VSCode command line to not respect the folder argument?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the shell script defined here (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup), and while I can type `code .` to open up VS Code, it does *not* select the current directory to show in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

<s>With the 0.3.0 update this issue has been fixed. Please use this updated command:</s>

```
code () {
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}
```

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:** please use the command `Install code command in path` from the command palette (View | Command Palette).

Comment: Wow! And it opened a second window too -which is perfect. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the sample on the setup page and it works fine.

```
code () {
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
        open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
    fi
}
```

I did however add it to the bottom of my **~/.bashrc**  instead of my **.bash_profile**.  The .bash_profile simply sources the .bash_profile so it should be equivalent.

```
if [ -e ~/.bashrc ] 
then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

You can test that you are running in a bash shell by executing:

```
echo $SHELL
```

This should return /bash/bash.

Comment: This only works if Code is closed. if Code was already open, it focuses it, but doesn't change directories.

Comment: The fact that Code is already open should have been stated in the original question.  In that case you could detect if it is already open and then run AppleScript to change the currently opened folder.  Unfortunately Visual Code does not currently have AppleScript or Automator support.  You could rewrite the bash function to shutdown code and reopen it if it is already open.  These solutions are complex and it might be better to simply use the File -> Open ... menu option.

Comment: We will look into this issue, it was reported already as a bug.